# Creating filter stage of type filters.height using PDAL?

Tags: lidar, point-cloud, normalize, pdal

I use PDAL to find the height of points from LiDAR data. When I run the command:

```
pdal translate myfile.las height.bpf height --writers.bpf.output_dims="X,Y,Z,Height;"
```

It throws me the following error:

> PDAL: Couldn't create filter stage of type 'filters.height'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`filters.height` has been replaced by `filters.hag` so if you want to find the Height Above Ground (HAG) in point cloud data use [filters.hag](https://www.pdal.io/stages/filters.hag.html#filters-hag):

```
{
  "pipeline":[
    "input.las",
    {
      "type":"filters.hag"
    },
    {
      "type":"filters.ferry",
      "dimensions":"HeightAboveGround = Z",
    },
    {
      "type":"writers.las",
      "filename":"output.las"
    }
  ]
}
```